# Convert Kotlin MutableMap to java.util.HashMap

Tags: java, kotlin, hashmap

I am working with a pretty old project that has a lot of java code in it, and to replace it, it will be too much of a hassle, and as kotlin is much better than java, I'm trying to coed all the new code in kotlin, but when I try to access a java code with this kotlin code

```
val params = mutableMapOf<String, String>(
    "name" to response.name,
    "type" to response.type
)
product.params = params
```

I got a red underline below the `params`, it said

```
Required: Hashmap<String!, Any!>!
Found: MutableMap<String, String>
```

This is my java setter

```
public void setParams(HashMap<String, Object> params){
    this.params = params;
}
```

Can I fix this without changing the java code? Please help if it is possible, or if it is not, and what is the workaround to fix this.

Comment: so why not use `Hashmap` instead of `mutableMapOf`

Comment: Well, it also gives me an error, Required: Hashmap<String!, Any!>! Found: Hashmap<String, String>

Comment: please check the answer @Fadel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`hashMapOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/hash-map-of.html) instead.

```
product.params = hashMapOf<String, Any?>(
    "name" to response.name,
    "type" to response.type
)
```

Answer (score 10):

You can construct a new `HashMap` from the params:

```
val params = mutableMapOf<String, String>(
    "name" to response.name,
    "type" to response.type
)
product.params = HashMap(params)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use HashMap<> istead mutableMapOf()

```
    val params = HashMap<String, String>()
    params.put("name", response.name)
    params.put("type", response.type)
    product.params = params
```

Comment: Still error,
Required: Hashmap<String!, Any!>!
Found: Hashmap<String, String>